# MinIO Signature Mismatch

Tags: reverse-proxy, amazon-eks, minio

I have set up MinIO behind a reverse proxy in EKS. Everything worked well until MinIO was updated to `RELEASE.2021-11-03T03-36-36Z`. Now I am getting the following error when trying to access my MinIO bucket using the `mc` command-line utility: `mc: <ERROR> Unable to list folder. The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method.`

`mc` version is `RELEASE.2021-11-16T20-37-36Z`. When I port-forward the MinIO container to localhost and access it in a browser at `http://localhost:9001` I can get to it, but I can't log in anymore. I get the error:

> Invalid Login, 403 Forbidden`. This is seen in my MinIO container

It also logs the following:

```
API: SYSTEM()
Time: 03:19:57 UTC 11/23/2021
DeploymentID: 60a8ed7a-7448-4a3d-9220-ff823facd54e
Error: The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method. (*errors.errorString)
       requestHeaders={"method":"POST","reqURI":"/minio/admin/v3/update?updateURL=","header":{"Authorization":["AWS4-HMAC-SHA256 Credential=<credential-scrubbed>/20211123//s3/aws4_request, SignedHeaders=host;x-amz-content-sha256;x-amz-date, Signature=37850012ca8d27498793c514aa826f1c29b19ceae96057b9d46e24599cc8081b"],"Connection":["keep-alive"],"Content-Length":["0"],"Host":["<host-info-scrubbed>"],"User-Agent":["MinIO (darwin; amd64) madmin-go/0.0.1 mc/RELEASE.2021-11-16T20-37-36Z"],"X-Amz-Content-Sha256":["<scrubbed>"],"X-Amz-Date":["20211123T031957Z"],"X-Forwarded-For":["10.192.57.142"],"X-Forwarded-Host":["<host-info-scurbbed>"],"X-Forwarded-Path":["/minio/admin/v3/update"],"X-Forwarded-Port":["80"],"X-Forwarded-Proto":["http"],"X-Real-Ip":["10.192.57.142"]}}
       5: cmd/auth-handler.go:154:cmd.validateAdminSignature()
       4: cmd/auth-handler.go:165:cmd.checkAdminRequestAuth()
       3: cmd/admin-handler-utils.go:41:cmd.validateAdminReq()
       2: cmd/admin-handlers.go:87:cmd.adminAPIHandlers.ServerUpdateHandler()
       1: net/http/server.go:2046:http.HandlerFunc.ServeHTTP()
```

When checking the proxy logs (NGINX), I see:

```
10.192.57.142 - - [24/Nov/2021:21:18:17 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 403 334 "-" "MinIO (darwin; amd64) minio-go/v7.0.16 mc/RELEASE.2021-11-16T20-37-36Z"
```

Any suggestions or advice on what I can do to resolve this would be great! I'm using the `mc` client on OSX.